# I need to report difference in median (or Median difference) and its 95% confidence interval

Tags: r, difference, median, confidence-interval

I have 2 unequal groups (pp and Control) and I reported median and 95% confidence interval for `waiting.time` variable for each group but now I want to report "Difference in median" and its 95% confidence interval. I found something similar but in `sas` ([Link here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/22/difference-of-medians-sas.html)) but I need to do it in `R`.

Here is a [data sample](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ8RhtXZvvucsTFnFXYUkncKFL4hUuv2VnQy)

```
library(tableone)
tab<-print(a<-CreateTableOne(vars = "waiting.time",  strata="group", 
                             data=data,  addOverall = T, ), nonnormal = "waiting.time");tab
```

Here is what I am looking for:
[image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122001/confidence-intervals-for-median) help?

Comment: @Limey Thx for your reply but this is not what I am looking for. I added a link to similar work but with sas code

Comment: Did you invest some time in simply googling "confidence interval median R"? If so, you might have found this: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/E_04.html or that: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21103/confidence-interval-for-median

Generally, bootstrapping seems to be a potential solution.

Comment: @deschen Thx for your reply. I saw them but they did not answer my question yet as I said I have 2 "unequal" groups. Also, they are distinct groups i.e. not before and after (not paired) although being randomized subjects. I reshaped the data so I have 2 columns for `waiting.time` now one for pp and 1 for control. Please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bootstrap the difference in medians and then compute quantiles can be done as follows.

### 1.

First read in the data.

```
data <- read.csv("~/Transferências/stackoverflow.data.csv")
str(data)
#'data.frame':  420 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ X           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ group       : chr  "Control" "Control" "PP" "Control" ...
# $ waiting.time: num  NA NA NA 23.9 NA ...
```

The data has `NA`'s and argument `na.rm = TRUE` will be used.

### 2.

Now bootstrap the statistic, function `boot_diff_median`.

```
library(boot)

boot_diff_median <- function(data, i){
  diff(tapply(data$waiting.time[i], data$group[i], FUN = median, na.rm = TRUE))
}

set.seed(2021)
R <- 1e4

b <- boot(data, statistic = boot_diff_median, R = R)
```

### 3.

Compute quantiles. I have also included the bootstrapped value, `mean(b$t)`.

```
mean(b$t)
#[1] -0.4330915

t(quantile(b$t, probs = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975), na.rm = TRUE))
#          2.5%  50%    97.5%
#[1,] -11.35525 -0.5 8.620875
```

Comment: I believe this makes sense rather my prior trials. Thx a lot. Greatly appreciated. Upvoted and marked as a solution.